# HTML pattern for email to a specific domain

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex pattern that only accepts email with a specific domain as follows.

z= [a-zA-Z0-9]

y= [a-zA-z]

(1) zzz.zzz@domain.y (eg: andrew.hugh@gmail.com, anne.dal@yahoo.ca)

(2) zzz.zzz@zzz.domain.y (eg: bryan.hawk@admin.msn.com, nick.deboer@info.school.edu)

Currently what I have so far is:
[.a-zA-z0-9]*@domain.[a-zA-z0-9]

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Would you mind if I write you a piece of JavaScript which is a bit nicer than Regex? Or is it required to be regex?

Comment: @JesseSchokker Can you do both?

Comment: I've answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are
for request no 1

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@domain\.[a-zA-z]+$
```

for request no 2

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.domain\.[a-zA-z]+$
```

Comment: Keep in mind to escape dots since they are used in regex.

Comment: If you are using html5: `<input type="email" name="pw" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9].domain.[a-zA-z]+$" title="Must be from the [domain] domain">`

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted text. fixed now to escape chars properly

Answer (score 2):

It might be a lot easier to make a JavaScript function out of this, instead of doing it with Regex. As you have said in the comments; you don't mind.

```
function matchesEmail( email ) {

    var acceptedEmails = [ "msn.com", "school.edu" ];

    for( key in acceptedEmails ) {

        var acceptedEmailDomain = acceptedEmails[ key ];

        if( email.split( "@" )[1].split(".").slice(-2).join( "." ) === acceptedEmailDomain ) {

            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

};

console.log( matchesEmail( "jesse@ddd.com" ) );
```

Comment: There are some bugs in this.  return false after one iteration through the array (I think you meant to put return false after the for loop not in it).  `.split(".").join(".")` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced the return false. It was not meant to be inside the loop as you pointed out. I've corrected this now.